# Ecto union_all with count(*) query

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
thirty_days_ago_completed_visits =
  from(v in Visit,
    select: %{a: count("*")},
    where: v.papa_id == ^papa.id,
    where:
      v.scheduled_for >= ^thirty_days_ago and
        v.state in ["completed", "reviewed"]
  )

sixty_days_ago_completed_visits =
  from(v in Visit,
    select: %{b: count("*")},
    where: v.papa_id == ^papa.id,
    where:
      v.scheduled_for >= ^sixty_days_ago and
        v.state in ["completed", "reviewed"]
  )

future_scheduled_visits =
  from(v in Visit,
    select: %{c: count("*")},
    where: v.papa_id == ^papa.id,
    where: v.recurring == false,
    where: v.scheduled_for >= ^Timex.now()
  )

future_recurring_visits =
  from(v in Visit,
    select: %{d: count("*")},
    where: v.papa_id == ^papa.id,
    where: v.recurring == true,
    where: v.scheduled_for >= ^Timex.now()
  )

from(
  a in subquery(thirty_days_ago_completed_visits),
  union_all: ^sixty_days_ago_completed_visits,
  union_all: ^future_scheduled_visits,
  union_all: ^future_recurring_visits
)
|> Repo.all()
|> IO.inspect()
```

And I'm getting this error:

** (Ecto.QueryError) subquery/cte must select a source (t), a field (t.field) or a map, got: `count("*")` in query:

```
from v0 in PapaPal.Visit,
  where: v0.papa_id == ^"419b3f7f-b74a-42fa-a377-2b7f54886c06",
  where: v0.scheduled_for >= ^#DateTime<2020-04-18 19:31:36.774112Z> and v0.state in ["completed", "reviewed"],
  select: count("*")
```

All I'm trying to end up with is four integers, one for each query - by using a **single SQL query** to the database.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for [`Ecto.Query.API.count/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html?#count/1), as well as the error message itself, clearly state that you have to *select a source, a field, or a map*, while you are passing `"*"` to it. The below would work.

```rb
from v0 in PapaPal.Visit,
  where: v0.papa_id == ^papa_id,
  where: v0.scheduled_for >= ^dt,
  where: v0.state in ^states,
  select: count(v0.id) # THIS
```